# Building a Dynamic Where Lambda for LinqToSql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I am trying to create a dynamic where clause to allow the user to choose a field and enter the filter criteria. I have tried so many solutions and just can't put it all together. I think I am close, but just can't get past this last error.

Here is the (dumbed down) method that should query my table of contacts and return a list of domain object Contacts.

```
internal static IEnumerable<Contact> GetContacts(int pageSize, int page, string searchField, string searchValue)
{
    var pageContacts = new List<Contact>();
    using (var db = new TLWDatabaseDataContext())
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TLW.Models.Contact), "t");
        // MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter);
        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(searchValue, searchValue.GetType());
        BinaryExpression exp = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, searchField), constant);
        Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> lambda1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Contact, bool>>(exp, param);

        IQueryable<Data.Contact> dbContacts = db.Contacts.AsQueryable();
        dbContacts = dbContacts.Where(lambda1);
        dbContacts = dbContacts.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        pageContacts.AddRange(dbContacts.Select(contact => new Contact
        {
            Address1 = contact.Address1,
            Address2 = contact.Address2,
            CellPhone = PrettyPhone(contact.CellPhone),
            City = contact.City,
            Created = contact.CreatedOn,
            Email = contact.Email,
            FirstName = contact.FirstName,
            HomePhone = PrettyPhone(contact.HomePhone),
            Id = contact.Id,
            LastName = contact.LastName,
            LastUpdated = contact.LastUpdated,
            State = contact.State,
            WorkPhone = PrettyPhone(contact.WorkPhone),
            Zip = contact.Zip
        }));
    }
    return pageContacts;
}
```

This is so close, but I have a compiler error on the line dbContacts = dbContacts.Where(lambda1).

There error is occurring because of a conversion when sending the lambda1 parameter to Where. The text of the error is...

Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'

TIA for any guidance. I have successfully create an Expression Tree for my OrderBy (removed from above code for brevity), but just can't get an Epression Tree working for the Where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Data.Contact` in both `param` and `lambda1` (instead of `TLW.Models.Contact` and `Contact`)

Comment: I just KNEW it was going to be something annoying like that. Thank you!